# Hosts file with port?

Tags: hosts

I know you can't put a port in /etc/hosts, so how can I achieve the equivalent of:

```
127.0.0.1     https://website.com:4433
```

For WordPress, I need CURL to go to 127.0.0.1 on port 4433. As it's wordpress and not a script I made, I can't change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find the iptables rule to fix my issue:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4433
```

Comment: This doesn't show any 'website.com' information.

Answer (score 2):

Add a line into your `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1      website.com
```

then configure your program (whatever it is) to listen on 4433 at 127.0.0.1.

And you're done.

---

Example:

```
echo hi | nc -lt 127.0.0.1 4433
```

now open `website.com:4433` and you should see a "hi".

to fix the problem you mentioned in the comments you can use `socat`:

```
socat tcp-listen:4433,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:xx
```

with the above command, `socat` will listen on `4433` and whenever a request came in in will forward it to the `xx`, so change the `xx` with the real port where your program is listening to.

Comment: I can't tell the program to listen on 4433

Comment: why can't you tell curl to listen to port 4433?

Comment: It's part of wordpress. I have a problem with WP-cron and I need it to redirect my domain name to localhost.

Comment: That's another question however I'll update my answer ;)

Comment: Is there an iptables rule to redirect localhost requests to port 443 to port 4433?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Chrome web browser, they have a URL aliasing app.  It's called URL Alias.  Just load it and define a web site.  In the definition, you can add the full URL with port designation.